# ObservableCollection<> won't bind changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a table in `WPF` to which I bind a `ObservableCollection<Message> TableData` list of type `Message`. I set the style of the table row in such a way that it can read the message `StatusColor`(change the color of the text). This works as fine when I add elements to the `ObservableCollection<Message>` but when I change `StatusColor` the change is not updated in the UI.

code:

```
public class Message 
{
    public string ShortTextMessage { get; set; }
    public string StatusColor { get; set; }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRow"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding StatusColor, Mode=TwoWay}"></Setter>
</Style>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableData}" SelectedItem="{Binding TableData, Mode=TwoWay}" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRow}" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
```

Answer (score 4):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your class `Message`:

```
 public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
            ValidateAsync();
        }
        #endregion
}
```

Inherit `ViewModelBase`:

```
public class Message:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _shortTextMessage;      
    public string ShortTextMessage 
    {
        get { return _shortTextMessage; }
        set
        {
            _shortTextMessage= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _statusColor;      
    public string StatusColor 
    {
        get { return _statusColor; }
        set
        {
            _statusColor= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

That should work.

Comment: This is how it is done!! Nice work! I don't know why the base class is not implemented by microsoft. Would be a nice feature. Additionally it would be cool if a developer can just define a PropertyChangedAttribute over the property. This way we could use autoproperties. :D

Comment: I'm glad to helo :)

Comment: You could also add C# 6 null-safe operator: `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`

Comment: Yeah, if you want to be trendy ))

Comment: Thanks, it totally makes sense to add the INotifyPropertyChanged to the class.